# How can I create a user-specific SharedPreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create a SharedPreference that is user specific. All I want to store is the layouts background depending on what is from the settings menu. How can I store and load SharedPreference depending on the Account being used?

Comment: Define a key unique to that account? i.e. use a username as an identifier

Comment: define Account...

Comment: This sounds like a problem best solved by using SQLite instead.

Comment: @MikiP I could have, but since this is a school project and there are mandatory items, i have to use sharedPrefences :/

Comment: @Selvin I have an sqlite db that contains Accounts for Users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your user id as a key for SharedPreference and then save your user details as object in it's value.
In this way you store User data for all users locally.

```
/*Save the object in shared Preferences*/
    public void saveObjectToPreferences(String key, Object value) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.PREF_FILE_CONFIG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        String jsonValue = new Gson().toJson(value);
        editor.putString(key, jsonValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    /*Get the object from shared Preferences*/
    public Object getObjectFromPreferences(String key, Object defaultObj) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ApplicationConstants.PREF_FILE_CONFIG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = prefs.getString(key, "");
        Object object = new Gson().fromJson(value, defaultObj.getClass());
        return object;
    }
```

Pass user id in key and details in object in these methods. it will work.

Comment: You could do this. You'll have to do a conversion to a format such as GSON in order to be able to store the object into SharedPrefs.

Comment: And for getting object, you can pass null.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a value field that contains the users information? Then you would search for the username and check it's children for corresponding information. You might have to store information as objects then.

If you are using Shared Preferences, it should only contain a small amount of key-value pairs. Since you are using a local database, I suggest storing your values there instead. You could have a table for each type of information you want to store, say High Scores. You would need a "USERID" field so that when you perform a search on the Database you could use the `where` clause to specify which USERID to search for. Once you have searched for the user's information you can store into Shared Preferences to make it easier to work with and only have a small amount of data as opposed to everyone's data. Once you're done with using the information you would save the information back to the DB.

Comment: I'm using a db for the accounts. Im new to android developing and haven't found quite anything understandable on how to properly make a sharedPrefence so I dont know how to link the two either

Comment: If you're using a db, then couldn't you store whatever is in Shared Preferences in there? Shared Preferences is for locally storing a small amount of key, value pairs. I find this link describes it pretty well and shows you how to read/write. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html See my edit for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Much appreciated mate